# Windows shell on Linux: Arrow keys and some commands doesn't works fine

Tags: linux, windows, shell, cmd.exe

My problems are explained in the following pictures. They occur when I use a windows shell on linux.

Picture 1: Problem with arrow keys (print A B C D, instead of moves):
[image]

Picture 2: Problem with some commands (freezes the session)
[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

The second one is easy - to exit FTP type

> bye

The first one - I can give you some guidance on what is wrong but not how to fix it.  The first key sequence is "ESCAPE[D" which is the VT100 terminal sequence for Move backwards. So you need to tell your system its not a VT100 terminal but something else that wants the key scan codes

I don't know how to do that. Maybe someone else does or you could ask that question directly